# WordPress unable to send mail

Tags: email, wp-mail, smtp

I am unable to get email functioning in WP 4.8.

I have WordPress running on a Bitnami LAMP stack. All modules/plugins/themes/languages are up to date.

I have an SMTP host that is effectively an open relay (coming from my network only) and so does not require or support authentication. I want to use this to deliver all SMTP from WordPress.

WordPress has the plugin WP-Mail-SMTP which allows basic email config and test. Using this plugin I have tried a combination of all the possible settings, all of which fail.

My ideal (I believe) setup would be:

> Send All WordPress email via SMTP 
>   SMTP Host : mailgateway.com.outbound.epasecure.com 
>   SMTP Port : 25 
>   Encryption : No Encryption 
>   Authentication : No: Do notuse SMTP authentication

The log output demonstrates the issue I am having is like this [Note : IP.AD.DRE.SS is a sanitized version of my WAN IP]

```
The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
 2017-10-09 14:43:40    Connection: opening to mailgateway.com.outbound.epasecure.com:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                          )
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    Connection: opened
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 out4d.electric.net ESMTP"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 out4d.electric.net ESMTP
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.50.94
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-SIZE 268435456"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-8BITMIME"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
                                          250-8BITMIME
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-PIPELINING"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-PIPELINING
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-AUTH LOGIN"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]"
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-AUTH LOGIN
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-STARTTLS"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-AUTH LOGIN
                                          250-STARTTLS
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250 HELP"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-out4d.electric.net Hello 192.168.50.94 [IP.AD.DRE.SS]
                                          250-SIZE 268435456
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-AUTH LOGIN
                                          250-STARTTLS
                                          250 HELP
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 TLS go ahead
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "221 out4d.electric.net closing connection"
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 out4d.electric.net closing connection
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    Connection: closed
 2017-10-09 14:43:41    SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

The crucial element here is as follows :

```
2017-10-09 14:43:41    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-10-09 14:43:41    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2017-10-09 14:43:41    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

The client is negotiating TLS despite the WP-Mail-SMTP config being set to not do so, and the relay I am sending via not requiring TLS to connect.

If I SSH to the WordPress server and TELNET to the SMTP relay I can do a manual email as follows:

```
>telnet mailgateway.com.outbound.epasecure.com 25
EHLO example.com
MAIL FROM:someone@example.com
RCPT TO:example@someone.com
DATA
TEST
.
```

This sends as expected.

As work-arounds I have tried to get this working with both sSMTP and most recently Postfix installed on the WordPress host.

I have configured Postfix as an open relay and telnet localhost 25 works and allows me to send mail via my normal relay.

When configuring WordPress to send via localhost:25 I get the same failure, the Client negotiates TLS, the server responds and the client quits.

I would like to prevent the client from offering TLS. How do I configure WordPress to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get this to work, as a work around I had to configure the WP-SMTPMail to send directly to our Office365 instance, which required an additional user to be configured.