# Mailing issues with wordpress?

Tags: email, smtp

I'm working on a client's website and they are not getting messages from the site anymore.

I've found that no mail will go to an email address ending in @gmail.com, I can send mail just fine to anyone within my company that has an email with a custom domain. But a Gmail inbox the messages never even seem to make get close. They're not in spam, not in promotions, nowhere.

I've installed WP mail log, and see no errors on the site. It doesn't appear to be an SMTP issue as I can send messages just fine.

I know this is not explicitly a WordPress issue but I've run out of ideas and options to try so if anyone has encountered this and has any ideas it would be appreciated.

Comment: just because it sent doesn't mean it will arrive, webhosts are notorious for sending spam and are rarely trusted by email vendors, or even the servers that sit in-between them. Different inbox providers may have different rules and policies about what they consider malicious or spam, and if the source is particularly untrustworthy it won't even reach the junk/spam folder. Your host will have better advice here as this isn't strictly a WordPress problem but a general PHP problem, unless you can use alternative SMTP credentials for sending that are more reputable

Comment: also see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377247/woocommerce-emails-from-gmail-not-being-sent?rq=1 and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282458/wordpress-unable-to-send-mail?rq=1

Comment: Yeah I ended up setting up gmail SMTP through the gmail API... super strange as this is not an issue with any other site... oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up setting up Gmail SMTP through the Gmail API, and this seemed to solve the problem in this case.